# Can I leave and return to Singapore using a short-term visit pass after cancellation of employment pass?

Tags: visas, singapore

I have a Singaporean employment pass which will be cancelled shortly and I will then be granted a 30 day short term visit visa in replacement.

My question: Can I travel to nearby countries for one week and return to Singapore? Or will my short-term visit pass be cancelled once I leave Singapore?

Comment: For interest, what's your citizenship?

Comment: Ask MOM: http://www.mom.gov.sg/contact-us/Pages/default.aspx - they are good about answering specific questions like this, and fairly prompt.  Then you can post your own answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my experience, which is the same as yours; this pass loses its validity once you depart from Singapore. It is not a multiple entry visa, but rather it is just something that makes your staying inside Singapore legal.